# How to Preserve Data in Specific Tables/Entities when using Doctrine2 Fixtures?

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, fixtures, preserve

I have three tables/entities for which I want to preserve their data when I load Doctrine2 fixtures. Of course, right now, when I run `doctrine:fixtures:load`, it purges the entire database (except migration_versions) and then loads the fixtures appropriately.

I realize that I can use the --append switch to only add data to the database, but I do want to remove most of the data from the database.

How do I preserve table data from only three tables/entities when using Doctrine2 fixtures?

Answer (score 2):

How about you separate the "append-only" and "delete-only" fixtures classes into separate folders and then run two console commands specifying the fixtures path using --fixtures ?